# setInterval time not precise

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm developping an ionic app.

I create a counter with setInterval.

```
let test = new Date().getTime();
setInterval(() => {

  console.log(new Date().getTime() - test);
  test = new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);
```

Problem, the console.log give not the answer 1000. It is completely random and sometimes more thant 3000.

Have you an idea why is it so?

Comment: There's no guarantee of accuracy with browser timers. They're usually pretty close. If your tab loses focus the browser will slow them way down.

Comment: setInterval only guarantees that the callback will be called at least n milliseconds later. So, if there are a lot of events in the callback queue, they will all have to finish before the setInterval callback is called.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee the exact time because even the simplest function like this it takes some millisecond to execute the content inside the interval function. `setInterval` function only guarantee the time interval.